# Battery icon missing in gnome-shell panel

Tags: 12.10, gnome, launcher, battery

I have lost the battery icon on panel when I rotated the screen using ccw (`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`) and can't get it back.

dconf editor → com → canonical → indicator → appmenu → power shows icon policy present , and show time visible but no battery icon showing up on panel .

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is installed with `sudo apt-get install indicator-power`

If that doesnt help try `gsettings list-recursively|grep settings-daemon` and look for  `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active false` if it is false use the following command:
`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true`.

Comment: org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active is already true.Battery icon  disappear only when rotate the screen.